# zerrorlines in Gnuplot's splot

Tags: statistics, plot, gnuplot

I wish to use error lines for some data in a 3D plot using splot command in GNUplot. Unfortunately, I am unable to find any documentation for this and fear that the functionality might be unavailable in gnuplot.

Is there a hack or an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you could structure your datafile as:

```
x1 y1 z1err_min
x1 y1 z1err_max

x2 y2 z2err_min
x2 y2 z2err_max
```

and then plot that datafile with lines to give you some sort of (very) poor man's error bars on 3d data.